# Select statement to prevent selecting null

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a model where `Person` has 0, 1 or 2 `Contact` objects.
Contact information home (contact_type is "h") and contact information for work (contact_type is "w").

Is there a way to check that the `Contact` object with `contact_type == "h"` exists when selecting street name? Right now I'm getting a null exception if the Contact object does not exist.

```
from m in persons
select new
{
    Id = m.id,
    Name = m.surname,
    Address = m.Contacts.Where(c => c.contact_type == "H").SingleOrDefault().streetname
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
var rows = from m in persons
    let h = m.Contacts.Where(c => c.contact_type == "H").SingleOrDefault()
    select new {
        Id = m.id,
        Name = m.surname,
        Address = (h == null ? null : h.streetname)
    };
```

or:

```
var rows = from m in persons
    select new {
        Id = m.id,
        Name = m.surname,
        Address = m.Contacts.Where(c => c.contact_type == "H")
                 .Select(c => c.streetname).SingleOrDefault()
    };
```

which could also be written (perhaps more clearly):

```
var rows = from m in persons
    select new {
        Id = m.id,
        Name = m.surname,
        Address = (from c in m.Contacts
                   where c.contact_type == "H"
                   select c.streetname).SingleOrDefault()
    };
```

Comment: I like the second one, it seems straight forward to me. Thanks a bunch =)

Answer (score 0):

You can have mulitple `Where` clauses:

```
Address = m.Where( person => person.Contacts != null ).Contacts.Where( ...
```

Comment: That only checks if `Contacts` is null; it doesn't check whether `H`-contact exists

Comment: @MarcGravell he combines multiple where clauses. The first one filters empty contacts, the second on will filter on contact type

Comment: @Wouter yes, but the problem (as I read it) is that it fails when there is no H contact. The above will **still** fail, unless something is done to the final obtaining of `.streetname`

Comment: @MarcGravell True, I'm assuming `Contacts` is a collection of non-null `Contact` objects

Comment: @Nick as am I; the question is: does it contain a H contact, or does it not contain a H contact?

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah - the penny drops :doh:

Comment: Let me know if I've been unclear on anything and I'll update the question.